# Windows 8 Consumer Preview XAML - Are there IoC frameworks currently working?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, ioc-container, windows-8, windows-runtime

When coding XAML I always use MVVM frameworks to seperate concerns in my projects. I used MVVM Light in Windows 8 Developer Preview but this framework is not ready yet for Consumer Preview, do you know any other frameworks that are working right now with the consumer preview or just the IoC?

Comment: Regarding MVVM Light: https://twitter.com/#!/LBugnion/status/177133676973400064 maybe you can wait?